# How to show buttons as grid on scroll view and tapped on button show more labels on beneath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have scroll view with buttons and i want to show more labels on beneath of selected button tapped  and remaining buttons are moved to next position
I am objective c 
Please any one can help me

My Code is here
  UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

```
for (int i = 0; i<83; i++){

    imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [imageButton setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];

   // [imageButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [imageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"books"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    [imageButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",i]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPossion, yPossion, 70, 60)];
    imageButton.highlighted=YES;
   [imageButton addTarget:self

                action:@selector(butnSelected:)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];


    xPossion += imageButton.frame.size.width+35;
    temp++;
    if (temp==3) {
        yPossion = imageButton.frame.origin.y+imageButton.frame.size.height+20;
        temp = 0;
        xPossion = 20;
        yPossion += imageButton.frame.size.width-15;
        [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width ,yPossion-50)];
    }

}
```

My target is set to screen as like below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC20c.jpg)

and when I click on one image i want to display sub categories like below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz7ro.jpg)

Comment: Add more data what you have tried?

Comment: Please explain more about your question.

Comment: Add an image of where your issue occurs???

Comment: user can select multiple categories at a time ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISTackView for your purpose. Add circular / category buttons as well as all other buttons in one stackview. Hide / show the sub categories button on click of circular / category button. One of the main advantages of the stack view is that it will automatically create Auto Layout constraints for each subview that's added to it. You also have finite control over how those subviews are sized and positioned. There are options to configure the sizing of the views, where they should be arranged, as well as how much padding should be between the subviews.

I would also give a try and let you know.